# How to do multiple substitutes?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the below formula

=IF(D3="","",IFERROR(INDEX('Project Scoring'!$O$5:$O$1145,MATCH(D3&"*",'Project Scoring'!$D$5:$D$1145, 0)), " "))

I'd like to know the best way about going about adding 6 nested substitutes on the cell this formula will be used. Essentially I will be replacing what is Index/Matched with a char rather than the full string.

Comment: that depends mainly on what you data looks like and what you're substituting.  See how to create a [mcve], also this [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IF(D5="","",IFERROR(INDEX('Project Scoring'!$O$5:$O$1145,MATCH(D5&"*",'Project Scoring'!$D$5:$D$1145, 0)), " ")), "Efficiency", "E"), "Compl/Risk/Legal", "R")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IF(D5="","",IFERROR(INDEX('Project Scoring'!$O$5:$O$1145,MATCH(D5&"*",'Project Scoring'!$D$5:$D$1145, 0)), " ")), "Efficiency", "E"), "Compl/Risk/Legal", "R")

Comment: I'd appreciate it if people stopped down voting for no reason. I answered my own question days ago. Thanks!